# NodeJS : Href of a table element

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, href

Maybe I'm missing out something basic

But for some reason this code is not working :

```
<tr class="students">
  <td><%=it%></td>
  <td class="rollNo" href="/documents/getDocs"><%=stud %></td>
  <td><%=classroom.studentNames[stud]%></td>
</tr>
```

The table is getting displayed, but nothing happens on clicking
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<td>` elements don't have href attributes. Use an [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

```
<td class="rollNo"><a href="/documents/getDocs"><%=stud %></a></td>
```